# How can I upgrade Google Colab disk space?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I've tried to change Google Colab's runtime type to python >> GPU but it only gives me 68 gb of free space instead of 358GB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GCP to run Colab, using method in this article.

https://medium.com/@senthilnathangautham/colab-gcp-compute-how-to-link-them-together-98747e8d940e

You can specify any disk space, ram, etc. But it is not free.